# Paste a string as a variable, not as executable code snippet, into IPython

Tags: python, copy-paste, ipython, magic-methods

I'm aware of the magic IPython `%paste` command, which is quite useful, if you have valid code to insert. Now I don't want to insert code, I just want to store some string from the copy buffer as a variable. Is there a simpler way to do that, except copying the string to some separate text editor and modifying it first?

Something like this would be nice, but none of them are working:

```
strvar = %paste
strvar = """%paste"""
```

P.S. The string is lengthy and contains special chars etc. so simple ctrl-c just creates garbage and error messages.

Comment: I know how %paste works. This was not the question, and I wonder if you read the question at all, before you downvoted it oO

Comment: If you open the triple quotes and then paste from the clipboard, there shouldn't be any error messages.

Comment: No, this just gives a "%paste" as a string, not the clipboard.

Comment: I mean literal paste (`Ctrl+V` or whatever).

Comment: Reopening because it's different than the parse error the other question was asking about

Comment: Open triple quotes and then using ctrl+v is another valid option, still %paste strvar is nicer, as it doesn't clutter your console with megabytes of buffer content. Using %paste strvar for a while now, I use quotes+ctrl+v only, when %paste strvar sometimes drops some weird parsing error about the content.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
%paste strvar
```

gives you a list of the lines from the copied text. You can do

```
strvar = '\n'.join(strvar)
```

to get the text in a single string.

Comment: It's actually a special list subclass - you can do `strvar.n` to get newline-joined text. Likewise `strvar.s` for space-separated.